# Unable to detect spaces or punctuation marks

Tags: java

Code basically doubles something like abc123 to abc246. Now the problem here is that it won't detect spaces or punctuation marks and it'll give me an error for the line int i = Integer.parseInt(sentence);. Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: This code asks for a user input sentence through Scanner.

```
        else
        {
            String woah = sentence;
            sentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\D", "");
            int i = Integer.parseInt(sentence);
            int j = i * 2 ;
            woah = woah.replaceAll("" + i, "" + j);
            System.out.println(woah);
        }
```

Comment: What is the desired result supposed to be for "foo888"?

Comment: What is "\\D"? If you meant it to be space, why not just write " "?

Comment: \\D is all Non Digits pretty much

Comment: How about creating a string of all characters (punctuation and spaces) that you need to check for and iterating over it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your regular expression("\D") doesn't work for you, it is working for me. Alternatively you can give the below regular expression a shot.

```
    sentence = sentence.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is solid, that should delete all non-digit characters. That line should only throw an Exception if there are no numbers in the String. This leads me to believe that you've made a mistake getting input.

Are you using `Scanner.nextLine` for input, or `Scanner.next`? You should use the former if you aren't using delimiters.

Comment: Oh. My. God. You Sir Are A Genius. Thank you so much.
Edit: Well after i fixed I see another problem. If i input integers in different parts such as 1woah1 the output will remain the same as the input.

Comment: Your code isn't accounting for integers that are separated. I'm guessing you want it to output `2woah2`? One suggestion is replace your parsing line with `sentence.replaceAll("\\D", " ");` so that you only have spaces and digits. Then trim sentence. Then run it through this regex `.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` so that you don't have multiple spaces. Now split using `sentence.split(" ");`. Now you have an array of integers in the form of strings. You can loop through that array and double each integer. Then the trick is to get the new doubled integers into your original string.

Answer (score -1):

Easier approach:

```
StringBuilder woah = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
   char c = sentence.charAt(i);

   if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
      number.append(c);
   } else {
      woah.append(c);
   }

   woah.append(Integer.parseInt(number.toString()) * 2);

   System.out.println(woah.toString());
}
```

Comment: This prints `foo161616` instead of `foo1766` when `sentence` is `foo888`.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you want. Edited my answer. The point is you don't need to use regex.